# Mysql Returning unnecessarily rows

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE name='Süleyman';
```

---

[image]

**Result :**

With my Query, I want to return only the row having `name="Süleyman"`, But MySQL is returning `name="Suleyman"` rows too!

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: Seems like a collation issue. The comparison is done according to a collation that treats `ü` as `u`, typically any language except German. Check your language/locale settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE name='Süleyman' COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

You can see a SQL fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/508b5d/2/0

Comment: This Command work successfully but in My Table options Charracter set is :utf8--UTF-8 unicode and collation utf8_general_ci?

Comment: Indeed, in those character sets there is a mapping for special characters when performing queries: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-sets.html . You can however append the above statement to queries for making exception and you should be fine.

Comment: I must create every specific characters column with Collation utf8_bin, than not necessary with command, Thank you very much "ice 13"

Comment: Now have another problem, not return value when i 'name=süleyman' (lowercase) write?

Comment: SOLVED with latin_1